# Lost X Randomly (Ubuntu now only boots to terminal)

Tags: 12.10, xorg, virtualbox, 64-bit, display

I have Ubuntu 12.10 x64 running in a VM in VirtualBox.  I was writing some code, and then I minimized the VM window for a few seconds.  I tried to open it back up, and it crashed (or had crashed sometime when it was minimized).  When I restarted, X was no longer starting, but I was able to log in to terminal and access my file system.

I did just change my screen configuration today (from Gnome's "Displays" configuration window) to 2 screens instead of 1.  It was working just fine for hours and then this happened.

Anyway, this is what I see with **dmesg**:

```
[   32.168521] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 80x30
[   32.168532] fb0: VESA VGA frame buffer device
...
[   35.114612] init: lightdm main process (1014) terminated with status 1
[   50.270170] init: failsafe-x main process (1347) terminated with status 1
```

**startx** gives me this:

```
[   487.758] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[   487.758] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[   487.758] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[   487.758] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[   487.758] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
        Using a default monitor configuration.
...
[   487.778] (EE) Screen(s) found, but none have a usable configuration.
[   487.778] 
Fatal server error:
[   487.778] no screens found
[   487.778] (EE)
...
```

**sudo Xorg -configure** gives me this:

```
(++) Using config file: "/home/xxx/xorg.conf.new"
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
Number of created screens does not match number of detected devices.
  Configuration failed.
```

After checking the xorg.conf.new file, it shows 3 screens and 3 devices.  I only have 2 monitors, though.  I tried changing my VM configuration between 1 and 2 screens -- neither configuration worked.  Not sure what else to try.

Comment: SOLVED.

I uninstalled Guest Additions.  Was able to start X after that.  This is the command I used: sudo /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-4.2.0/uninstall.sh

Comment: This was exactly the issue I was facing: https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/11709

Comment: If it's solved, please add an answer and accept that. This way, it will be easier to know that it was actually solved.

Comment: I have to wait 8 hours to do that apparently -- very irritating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled Guest Additions. Was able to start X after that. This is the command I used:

```
sudo /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-4.2.0/uninstall
```

This was exactly the issue I was facing: https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/11709